# Javascript: How to hide properties of an object?

Tags: javascript, object, instance, loops, for-in-loop

I would like to make some properties of an object to be hidden and some to be visible on iteration. So I tried to use prototype but that's not working:

```
​function Car(){}

Car.prototype.version = '1.0';

var car_instance = new Car();
car_instance.make = 'BMW';
car_instance.model = 'x5';

for(property in car_instance){
    document.body.innerHTML += property + '<br>';
}
```

But this outputs `version` too:

```
make
model
version
```

I really like the idea to hide some functions/methods but access it easily like `car_instance.version`, and in fact if I console.log the object it has other properties too under **proto** which are not included in the for in loop.

So how should I solve this?

Comment: Prototype makes it so that each new instance of the object has that property.  It's especially useful for methods and memory conservation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to "hide" a property from a `for in` loop which *is* a direct property of the instance, you could use `Object.defineProperty`:

```
Object.defineProperty(car_instance, "version", {
  value: "1.0",
  writable: true,
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: false  // don't make it appear in a for in loop
});
```

Comment: But with some restriction: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Browser_compatibility

Comment: `Object.keys` won't show the property, but `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` and `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols` will, unfortunately - `enumerable` does not help there.

Answer (score 6):

To create a private variable, you will have to declare it inside function since JS has functional scope:

```
function Car(){
  // private var
  var version = '1.0';
  // public var
  this.foo = 'something';
}
```

When iterating over an object, use [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty) to get the actual object properties only:

```
for(property in car_instance){
   if (car_instance.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
     document.body.innerHTML += property + '<br>';
   }
}
```

**More Info:**

http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Comment: and can I call it on the instance like `car_instance.version`? I tried it and doesn't works http://jsfiddle.net/dZm8f/1/

Comment: @CIRK: No since it is private, as per the principles of OOP a private var is not accessible to outside world. If you need it outside then it will be public then.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(property in car_instance){
    if (car_instance.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        document.body.innerHTML += property + '<br>';
    }​
}
```

It outputs:

```
 make
 model
```

Or alternatively:

```
var car = Object.create(null);
​car.make = 'BMW';
car.model = 'x5';

for(property in car) {
    document.body.innerHTML += property + '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Skip Named Properties:

```
function Car(){
   this.private = {};
}

var inst = new Car();
inst.private.version = '1.0';
inst.make  = 'BMW';
inst.model = 'x5';

for(prop in inst){
    if (prop==='private') continue;        // skip named property
    console.log(prop);
}
```

Using a different data model.  The advantage is you can skip one property in the loop and because that property is an object, you can put any number of key/values in it.